# Filter by parameters sql vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, parameters, oledb

I have the following query:

```
Dim anything as oledbcommand ("select * from table where col1=@a0 , col2=@a1")
```

I will use this query for filtering.

As a result, I need records from col1 but without making a new select command.

So the question is:
What is the value of `@a0` to get all records?

Comment: I don't understand your question "What is the value of `@a0` to get all records?" Please provide more infos

Comment: It´s not possible with one Select statement. But this comes close: `select = "Select * from table Where {0} and col2=@a1"` then set condition based on filter: `query = string.format(select, if(filter = "all", "1=1", "col1=@a0")`

Comment: Thanks..But why u use {0} after where instead of col1=@a0

Comment: My dear @pirvu georgian ..i want to all records when a paramter...so i dont know the value of that paramter which give all records like i didnt use the paramter at first......and the reason is i have many conditions like col1=first one or col1=second one or col1=all names

Comment: because there is no value you can put into parameter @a0 which will give you all the results. It just not exist in sql.

Comment: Okay thanks ...i will try it @alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `like` operator and '%' character. '%' means any count of any character that matches all items.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [_Items] LIKE '%'
```

Comment: good answer but i have to get a parameter to filter my results

Comment: salam @Ahmed Ramdan  neede a little try! use parameter name instead of '%' and ...       
`    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [_Items] LIKE @Param
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param","%")